# rxjs simple do http get does nothing

Tags: javascript, http, typescript, angular, rxjs

I have code:

```
export class Test {

constructor(private http: Http) {}

logResponse(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('http://google.com')
    .do(data => console.log("All: " +  JSON.stringify(data)));
  }
}
```

But still, nothing gets printed out to the console sadly. I am just starting with Rxjs, so sorry for the lame question. Why is it not logged ? I have all the http and imports needed, no exception just nothing gets printed. I trigger it on a button press.

Comment: Looks like you need a promise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add first `subscribe` to activate that. This observable is cold ([hot vs cold observables](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339#.8xyy7ec8n)).

So in your case:

```
logResponse(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('http://google.com')
    .do(data => console.log("All: " +  JSON.stringify(data)))
    .subscribe(data => console.log("All from subscribe: " +  JSON.stringify(data)));
  }
}
```